# How to remove borders of the <header> tag?

Tags: html, css

Here's my code :

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
header {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

And what it looks like in my browser:

[image]

So my question is : **how** do I remove these white borders ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put in your question and full `html` and `css`, because the problem can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not actually borders, they're margin/padding. Browsers typically apply a default margin to the `<body>` tag and a variety of other elements.

You can apply `margin: 0; padding: 0;` on the `body` tag to fix this, but a better solution to prevent other similar issues is by starting with a CSS reset (http://www.cssreset.com/) and/or normalizer (http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).